# typescript: How to extend existing module definition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a declaration file written for extsting npm package, but seems like one method was not declared, I try to declare it, but get an error. Help me please.

structure of existing d.ts file:

```js
declare module "mongoose" {
...
  class Document {}
  interface Document extends MongooseDocument, NodeJS.EventEmitter, ModelProperties {
    increment(): this;
    remove(fn?: (err: any, product: this) => void): Promise<this>;
    ...
  }
}
```

I try to add to interface Document method deleteOne. My custom.d.ts:

```js
declare module "mongoose" {
  interface Document {
    deleteOne(fn?: (err: any, product: this) => void): Promise<this>;
  }
}
```

But still I get an error "Property 'deleteOne' does not exist on type".

Here is my tsconfig.json if you need:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "removeComments": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "pretty": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "ES2018",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
          "*": [
              "node_modules/*"
          ]
      }
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist",
      "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
  }
```

My custom.d.ts file located in 'src/' dir.

Comment: Can you not use the standard ```@types/mongoose``` in your code? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose

Comment: @skyhavoc it is already @types/mongoose. And also it is important to me to learn how to declare, not just use module

Comment: Could it be because your `document` interface is not extending?
`interface Document extends MongooseDocument, NodeJS.EventEmitter, ModelProperties`?

Comment: @hazardous I tried to extend, but got the same result  - error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK! Now I know this is expected behavior of ts-node: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types

I have configured paths settings in tsconfig.json, and now everything is working:

```json
    "paths": {
        "mongoose": ["src/custom.d.ts"],
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to use reexport in my case to merge declarations. typescript 4.0.5

`global-axios.d.ts`:

```
export * from 'axios';

declare module 'axios' {
    export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
        myConfigOption?: boolean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked great for me as well. Needed to add a missing type for mixpanel.

Answer (score 1):

defining the Mongoose interface

```
// types/mongoose/index.d.ts
declare module 'mongoose' {
  namespace Mongoose {
    export interface MyInterface {
      name: number;
    }
  }
}
```

usage

```
// app.ts
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
const a: Mongoose.MyInterface = {
  name: 122
};
```

I have also added `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./server/types"],` to my tsconfig file

does this help

Comment: it is not worked, but it was a good hint to me - to change my tsconfic file