# How to extend the types in tsconfig while maintaining the default behavior

Tags: typescript

According to [TypeScript's docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types), setting a value in `types` will override the default behavior and only look for the types I specified:

> By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible. For example, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included in the global scope. For instance:
>
> ```
>  "compilerOptions": {
>    "types": ["node", "jest", "express"]
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> This tsconfig.json file will only include ./node_modules/@types/node, ./node_modules/@types/jest and ./node_modules/@types/express. Other packages under node_modules/@types/* will not be included.

Is there a way I could **extend** the default behavior by supplying an additional type that is not listed inside "@types" rather than overriding it?

Comment: What about [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots)? You can specify the directory of your needed declarations and it should be treated just like `@types`.

Comment: It will override the default behavior of typeRoots

Comment: You can add your `types.d.ts` file to `include`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704510/16906055

Comment: When you say "an additional type", do you mean a single type or a folder of types?

Answer (score 1):

As @mseyfayi kindly gave you the hint, you can use the benefit of `Modules .d.ts`

[Modules .d.ts - TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)

**The below question and answers might help you.**

**[typescript: How to extend existing module definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046930/typescript-how-to-extend-existing-module-definition)**

this might help you too [Missing Types](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types) (from the post above)

---

This is not exactly what you want, but just for the sake of FYI

### Optional Global Usage

You can use export as namespace to declare that your module will be available in the global scope in UMD contexts:

[What is UMD? - TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-plugin-d-ts.html)

```
// declarations.d.ts
export as namespace moduleName;
```

---

don't forget to add the `.d.ts` file to your `tsconfig.json`

now it's available gloablly.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "include": [ declarations.d.ts ],
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i got this correctly but what you can do is to create a **tsconfig.json** and extend that.

So here you have a **tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "types": ["node", "jest", "express"]
 }
}
```

and then you have another **tsconfig.my.json** where

```
{
  "extends": "./configs/tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": ["main.ts", "yadayada.ts"]
}
```

Is it what you're looking for?